# How to make horizontal boxes auto stack vertically based on screen width?

Tags: html, css

I have this simple boxes inside a bordered frame, the frame has a max width.

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 1000px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.inner {
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 10px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class='outer'>

  <div class='inner'>1</div>
  <div class='inner'>2</div>
  <div class='inner'>3</div>
  <div class='inner'>4</div>
  <div class='inner'>5</div>
  <div class='inner'>6</div>
  <div class='inner'>7</div>
  
</div>
```

You can see as screen width reduces, the boxes get out of the frame. My question is, can those boxes automatically stack vertically inside the frame, so when screen width reduces, 7 goes under 1, then 6 under 1, 7 under 2, then 5 under 1, 6 under 2, 7 under 3, etc.

When screen width reduces to a minimum, just 1 column remains, follow 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 vertically.

In real app I have random number of boxes, so the stack needs to be automatic.

Comment: I'm having trouble visualizing what you mean, How can 6 and 7 both be under 1 at the same time? How can 7 be under both 1 and 2?

Comment: Just add `flex-wrap: wrap;` to `.outer`

Comment: I meant as screen width reduces, first 7 goes under 1. If screen width reduces more, then 6 is pushed to 2nd row so 6 under 1, 7 under 2, and so on

Comment: @AStombaugh oh no, so simple... can you add an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @one-hand-octopus Someone already did, you can accept his

Comment: [This page](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is personally my bible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for `flex-wrap: wrap;`

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 1000px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.inner {
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 10px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class='outer'>

  <div class='inner'>1</div>
  <div class='inner'>2</div>
  <div class='inner'>3</div>
  <div class='inner'>4</div>
  <div class='inner'>5</div>
  <div class='inner'>6</div>
  <div class='inner'>7</div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Good answer for simplicity with the existing approach. However, this causes a white space issue and does not utilize the full width of the container as the width has to be fixed. If the width is not fixed it will not use a clean cellular layout (which also prevents the usage of `flex-grow`). If a table-like layout is intended and the full width should be utilized then CSS-Grid should be used (which has a similar guide in detail and quality as your "bible" from eh same author on the same site).

Comment: @tacoshy What do you mean "whitespace issue?" Could any whitespace concerns not be acknowledged with `justify-content`? OP asked how to align his current items in this manner, changing them somewhat changes the scope of the question

Comment: white space is all free space. `justify-content` can align the boxes differently but the whitespace would still remain. Set your with of the container to 580px and you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

to make flex boxes be columns, use the CSS

```
flex-direction: column;
```

You can find this and more from my source:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox_container.asp

Comment: It misses more detailed information such as the usage of `media queries`. However, it is an unnecessary and complicated solution for this case. `flex-wrap` would be sufficient and add simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can and should be solved with CSS-Grid. This ensures that the columns are respected in every case and that the container will utilize the full width and not remain a white space caused by the `flex-wrap` (which is the major downside of @Libra's answer).

You can make use of the `auto-fit` and `minmax` values. This will ensure that an element has a minimum width and will occupy the rest. It will then fit as many elements next to each other as possible and push the other elements to the next rows but respect the columns:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
}

/* for visualization purpsoe only */
.container {
  gap: 0.5em;
}

.container > div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  background: blue;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
</div>
```